# Cookie isolation for testing

Tags: http, testing, selenium, load-testing, phantomjs

I would like several instances of a web-page at once for testing.
Each time with a different user, and hence a different cookie.

To save time, I would like to run these tests in parallel.
The problem is that browser instances share cookies. Hence two users cannot be logged in on the same computer on the same browser in different windows at the same time.

I am looking for a way to run several pages with different cookies at the same time.
I am open to any solution: PhantomJS, Selenium, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure that the selenium instances of firefox dont share cookies.
 You can go with selenium.
 What happens is, when a selenium session is invoked, it creates a temporary profile of the browser in the TEMP directory(for Windows) and performs all the operations on it. 
 **You can do yours as follows** 
Create a firefox profile, and configure it such that it never  remembers the history and use that profile to invoke browser . 
 For other browsers, keep the default settings as that they never remember the History

Answer (score 0):

After login you can try deleting cookies for the current session by using **selenium.deleteAllVisibleCookies()** method of selenium RC.

Comment: But this would delete cookies on my other concurrently open web-pages. See the problem in this sequence: 1: Page1_get_cookie 2:Page2_get_cookie 3:Page1_use_cookie 4:Selenium_delete_cookies 5:Page2_use-cookie-->ERROR!

Comment: Then try selenium.deleteCookie("CookieName","Path");.Hope this would help u.

Answer (score 0):

As you may be aware, cookies are bound to domains.

If you could get each page or tab to use a slightly different domain (like an alias), then these cookies could coexist.

This domain aliasing could be accomplished using proxy server.

I've gotten results in the past using Privoxy.

Recently, I've tried using mitmproxy which I've written about here.

https://gist.github.com/sharedvices/6098357